# Why isn't my code able to embed an NSUserDefault call within a UIImage assignment?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, nsuserdefaults

I would like to set the .image property of a UIImage to a variable as specified by a NSUserDefault value. However, I am getting some error that doesn't make sense!

Here is my code:

```
NSString *currentSample = [defaults stringForKey:@"selectSample"];
_mySample.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"%@", currentSample];
```

...or even better:

```
_mySample.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"%@", [defaults stringForKey:@"selectSample"]];
```

But  keep getting an error stating "too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2."  Can someone please help me debug this simple code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass a format string and a substitution when you're just using a string literal. Do

```
_mySample.image = [UIImage imageNamed:currentSample];
```

Instead.

If you did need substitutions, you'd still be passing a format string and the substitutions where you should pass only a single string... try

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Something that needs formatting %@", currentSample]; 
_mySample.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

instead.